# iOS: I am having a hard time with delegate definition

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, tableview

So I know what a delegate is and I know how to implement it and everything, but this definition throws me off a little bit. "Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object." Can someone explain how this applies to something like this 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ? What are the two objects and which object act on behalf of another object. I have an idea on what it is, but I need to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the table view controller (presumably that's the table view's delegate) acts on behalf of the table view. The class that implements the delegate method(s) acts on behalf of the class that defines the delegate interface.

Comment: Cool, this is what I thought. Had to make sure. Also, I dont know if this is true or not, but someone said delegate design pattern is basically an object sending a message to another object. Like tableviewcontroller sending number of cells count to table view.

Comment: That's exactly right. When the table view needs to know how many sections are in the table, the table view calls the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method on the delegate. Any method call is "sending a message to an object".

Comment: @user3435527 If this answered your question you should close it by accepting the answer. Click on the checkmark next to the answer.